# Regex help for url matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to distinguish different urls, patterns are:

```
https://example.com/ab-cd
https://examplle.com/34@b

https://example.com/ab-cd/ddss
https://examplle.com/34@b/nde3@
```

Form the urls above, the first 2 is one level down after `https://example.com` and the last 2 is two level down.

How can I write a regex in javascript to know the ones are one level down and two level down.

Thanks

Comment: no need to use regex for such simple task

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest what is the simple way? thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to use regex for such simple task.
Consider the following approach using `String.split` function:

```
var getUrlLevel = function (url) {
    return url.replace("//", "").split("/").length - 1;
};

console.log(getUrlLevel("https://example.com/ab-cd"));  // 1
console.log(getUrlLevel("https://examplle.com/34@b/nde3@/section"));  // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var level = url.replace(/[^\/]/g, "").length - 2;
```

Would get the job done.